# How to interrupt google assistant speech?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I've created Dialogflow, that reads names of products in a 20 items list. Once user heard the right product name, he needs a way to stop assistant from reading further and get to the right product.

Unfortunately there seems to be no way to let users interrupt google assistant speech. Are there ways around that? Does google intend to solve this problem in the near future?

Answer (score 4):

Users can interrupt what the Assistant is saying with the usual prefix of "Hey Google" or "Ok Google" followed by their answer.

*However*... reading a list of 20 items is generally not a very good VUI design. Even looking at a list of 20 items would be a poor visual UI in many cases, but listening to it would be. Imagine walking into a restaurant and having the following conversation:

> Waiter or clerk: "What would you like to eat today?"
>
> You: "Well, what do you have?"
>
> Waiter: "We have roasted chicken with asparagus, fried chicken with country style gravy, barbecue chicken with waffle fries, a chicken salad sandwich with walnuts and cranberries, that same chicken salad on a bed of lettuce with tomatoes, fried chicken livers, chicken and dumplings, grilled chicken tenderloins, fried chicken tenderloins, chicken nuggets, hot chicken nuggets, dinosaur chicken nuggets, buffalo chicken wings, boneless buffalo chicken wings, chicken soup with noodles, chicken soup with rice, chicken pot pie, fried chicken drumsticks, a chickenburger patty on a brioche bun, or our deluxe hamburger. What would you like?"

As humans, our tendency would not be to interrupt the waiter while they're talking, for starters, and the information they're presenting is quite overwhelming.

In a restaurant, we tend to have menus, but don't necessarily rely on them. (While there is a printed menu, you can often ask what the specials are for the day, or what they suggest.) Similarly, you can use display options for when the user is on a display capable device, but also be prepared to say things.

When saying things, limit it to two or three items at a time and offer more. Even after offering more, however, be prepared for them to ask for anything from the list.